# Create table into PostgreSql from Geoserver SQL View query

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I know how to connect Geoserver to PostgreSql and create SQL View queries with parameters from Geoserver, but ;it is possible to create a new table into PostgreSql from a Geoserver Sql View with parameters like this?:

Geoserver:

```
SELECT source FROM pgr_nearest_node('net',%lat%,%long%)
```

Comment: Why would you not do this directly in Postgres?

Comment: Hello John. Thanks for your comment. From Postgres,how it would be possible? . I would like to use Php to do some queries over the Geoserver Sql view WMS layer generated, therefore this layer should be into PostgreSql Data Base like a Table but i don't know if that depends on Geoserver or PostgreSql configuration.